# How to find a local variable declaration in an AST object

Tags: solidity, javascript, parser

How can I find the exact location of where a local variable was declared from an AST object?

I am using `solidity-parser-antlr` to visit AST nodes. Lets say this is a sample Solidity code that we have:

```
string public notRevealedUri;

function setNotRevealedURI1(string memory _notRevealedURI) public onlyOwner {
  notRevealedUri = _notRevealedURI;
}

function setNotRevealedURI2(string memory _notRevealedURI) public onlyOwner {
  notRevealedUri = _notRevealedURI;
}

function setNotRevealedURI3(string memory _notRevealedURI) public onlyOwner {
  notRevealedUri = _notRevealedURI;
}
```

If I want to find the variable `_notRevealedURI` that is inside `setNotRevealedURI2`, this is the function I have:

```
const myFunction = (ast, varToFind = "_notRevealedURI") => {
    parser.visit(ast, {
        VariableDeclaration: (node) => {
            if (
                node.name === varToFind
                // && node.isStateVar
            ) {
                console.log(node);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

The above function will return a 3 different locations - which are the parameter within `setNotRevealedURI1` `setNotRevealedURI2` and `setNotRevealedURI2` but I want to limit it to the correct reference which is the parameter inside `setNotRevealedURI2`. How can I achieve this?